# Use program to automatically work with command prompt in C++

Tags: c++, command-prompt

When I use the function `system()` to do something especially when it needs me to type something, is there any method to send message from the program to command prompt rather than ask users to type in?
Because I want this program to be **automatic**.

This is what i am doing:

```
system("openssl enc -des3 -in HomeController.class -out cipher.des");
```

Then the command prompt ask me to type in key(password):
"enter des-ede3-cbc encryption password:"

I have stored the key in my program, in string type.
Please help me to send this key to command prompt so I can let the program work automatically.

Comment: I'm pretty sure openssl has an option to read the password from the file, so you can simply save the password in a temporary file, and pass the appropriate parameter to openssl, and with a little bit of work this can even be made secure. In fact there is, indeed, such an option, as I just read openssl's manual page, and found it. You can also read openssl's manual page yourself for more information. Knowing where to find and read technical documentation is something that every C++ developer should know how to do.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik thks
Yes, i found the command but from other website.
openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -a -salt -in <raw data> -out <encrypted data> -pass file:<random key>

Comment: "If all you have is a hammer, then everything looks like a nail."  Would probably not use C++ to accomplish this.  Batch, Bash, VBS, Python, etc..

Answer (score 0):

Encrypt:Replace "random key" with your key.

```
openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -a -salt -in <raw data> -out <encrypted data> -pass file:"random key"
```

Decrypt:Replace "random key" with your key.

```
openssl enc -d -a -aes-256-cbc -in <ciphered data> -out <raw data> -pass file:"random key"
```